# Is there a consistent method for both cbind(1, <numeric>) and cbind(1, <matrix>)?

Tags: r

I'm working with some code that has crucial similarities to the following trivial script:

```
scores <- matrix(rnorm(4*20), ncol=4,nrow=20)
result <- matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=20)
index <- as.logical(rbinom(20,1,.2))
result[index, 1:3] <- cbind(1, scores[index,3:4])
```

where index is a logical vector and the `sum(index)` is typically greater than `1`but can occasionally be `1` or `0`.

The script fails in the case where `sum(index) == 1`:

```
> scores <- matrix(rnorm(4*20), ncol=4,nrow=20)
> result <- matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=20)
> index <- c(rep(FALSE, 19),TRUE)
> result[index, 1:3] <- cbind(1, scores[index,3:4])
Error in result[index, 1:3] <- cbind(1, scores[index, 3:4]) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> cbind(1, scores[index,3:4])
     [,1]       [,2]
[1,]    1 -0.1780255
[2,]    1 -0.6840048
> #should be:
> c(1, scores[index,3:4])
[1]  1.0000000 -0.1780255 -0.6840048
```

and where `sum(index) ==0`:

```
> scores <- matrix(rnorm(4*20), ncol=4,nrow=20)
> result <- matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=20)
> index <- rep(FALSE, 20)
> result[index, 1:3] <- cbind(1, scores[index,3:4])
Warning message:
In cbind(1, scores[index, 3:4]) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
> #cbinding to a zero-row matrix returns an error
```

The obvious solution to this problem is the following:

```
scores <- matrix(rnorm(4*20), ncol=4,nrow=20)
result <- matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=20)
index <- as.logical(rbinom(20,1,.1))
if(sum(index) > 1){
    result[index, 1:3] <- cbind(1, scores[index,3:4])
}else{
    if(sum(index) ==1){
        result[index, 1:3] <- c(1, scores[index,3:4])
    }
}
```

However, I'm interested in advice on how to code to avoid this error without having to write a bunch of `if` statements. Is there a trick to binding an atomic vector to an nx2 matrix OR 2-length vector (n=1) such that the result is always an nx3 matrix?  Extra points if the script can do this without producing an error when n=0.

If it weren't for like an hour of debugging, I wouldn't have identified this issue--it was buried quite a few functions down in a batch processing script.  Any general advice on coding in a way of avoiding such 'gotchas'?

Comment: Also, in general if an application is performance-sensitive, cbind will make you cry.

Comment: Good point--this is in the context of batch processing, so I'm sure the cbind slows things down. If I had written the original code I would have done everything in `data.table`, but since I'm just fixing and expanding someone else's code it would be a lot of work to start from scratch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally adding `drop=FALSE` to `mtx[1,]` calls will avoid the difficulties that arise with single row extractions and subsequent operations that assume a matrix structure:

```
result[index, 1:2] <- cbind(1, scores[1, 3:4, drop=FALSE])  # no error
# Also adding a third column to avoid dimension mismatch
scores <- matrix(rnorm(4*20), ncol=4,nrow=20)
result <- matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=20)
index <- as.logical(rbinom(20,1,.2))
result[index, 1:3] <- cbind(1, scores[index,3:4, drop=FALSE])
```

I haven't quite figured out how you want us to do to avoid errors with assignment of zero row objects to zero row objects. You should instead check for `length(index)==0`

(The real problem is that you were assigning a three column matrix to a two column target. Oh, I see you tried to fix that, except you were still trying to assign to a third column that was not there in the dimensions.)

Comment: Actually, assignment of a zero row object to a zero row object does not produce an error--it does nothing as you might expect. (try `index <- rep(FALSE, 20);result[index, 1:2] <- scores[index,3:4]`)  I guess it would make sense that concatenating to a 0x2 matrix would make an error. I guess i could write a function that would just return a 0 x 3 matrix, which is what would be needed for this to work in the 0x2 case.